# realm array index out of bounds

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, realm

I want to save data into realm if the user clicks on a button. Moreover the view should be updated if the user clicks that button. I have the following code:

```
    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentLogWeightTextField.text!.isEmpty || currentLogRepsTextField.text!.isEmpty || currentLogRPETextField.text!.isEmpty {
        errorLabel.isHidden = false
        return
    }
    else{
        if let weight = Float(currentLogWeightTextField.text!), let reps = Int(currentLogRepsTextField.text!), let rpe = Float(currentLogRPETextField.text!){
            errorLabel.isHidden = true
            let setToSave = excercisesFromPlan![excerciseCounter].sets[setCounter]
            do{
                try realm.write{
                    setToSave.weight = weight
                    setToSave.repeats = reps
                    setToSave.rpe = rpe
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else{
            errorLabel.isHidden = false
            return
        }
        if setCounter < excercisesFromPlan![excerciseCounter].sets.count{
            setCounter += 1
            setupLabels()
            print(setCounter)
            print(excercisesFromPlan![excerciseCounter].sets.count)
        }
        else{
            let finished = plan!.excercises.count - 1
            if excerciseCounter == finished{
                performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.finishedWorkout, sender: nil)
                return
            }
            else{
            excerciseCounter += 1
            setCounter = 1
            setupLabels()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my setupLabel method:

```
    func setupLabels(){
    if let excercise = excercisesFromPlan?[excerciseCounter]{
        excerciseNameLabel.text = "\(excercise.name)"
        setsNumberLabel.text = "\(setCounter)/\(excercise.sets.count)"
    }
}
```

These are the relevant properties:

```
var excercisesFromPlan: List<Excercise>?
var plan: TrainingPlan?
var excerciseCounter = 0
var setCounter = 1

excercisesFromPlan = plan?.excercises
```

The plan property is given through a segue.

These are my model classes:

```
class TrainingPlan: Object {

dynamic var trainingPlanID = NSUUID().uuidString

dynamic var routine: Routine?
dynamic var workout: Workout?
dynamic var selected = false
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var trainingPlanDescription = ""
dynamic var creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
dynamic var lastChangeDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
dynamic var lastUsed = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
let excercises = List<Excercise>()

override class func primaryKey() ->String?{
    return "trainingPlanID"
}
```

}

```
class Excercise: Object {

dynamic var excerciseID = NSUUID().uuidString

dynamic var trainingsplan: TrainingPlan?
dynamic var selected = false
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var excerciseDescription = ""
dynamic var muscleGroup = ""
dynamic var record = 0
dynamic var picture: NSData?
dynamic var copied = false
let sets = List<TrainingSet>()


override class func primaryKey() ->String?{
    return "excerciseID"
}

override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["name"]
}
```

}

I have the problem that if I use this code and click the save button, the Labels are updating right and the counter are also working. The only problem is that the else statement

```
else{
            let finished = plan!.excercises.count - 1
            if excerciseCounter == finished{
                performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.finishedWorkout, sender: nil)
                return
            }
            else{
            excerciseCounter += 1
            setCounter = 1
            setupLabels()
            }
        }
```

is never been called. I'm searching for the problem for a few hours now but I can't find it.. 
Strangely, if I comment out the following from the save function it works perfectly and the else statement is called right:

```
if let weight = Float(currentLogWeightTextField.text!), let reps = Int(currentLogRepsTextField.text!), let rpe = Float(currentLogRPETextField.text!){
            errorLabel.isHidden = true
            let setToSave = excercisesFromPlan![excerciseCounter].sets[setCounter]
            do{
                try realm.write{
                    setToSave.weight = weight
                    setToSave.repeats = reps
                    setToSave.rpe = rpe
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else{
            errorLabel.isHidden = false
            return
        }
```

Sorry for so much code.. Does anyone know why this is not working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it wasn't for the fact that you say the labels are updating I'd say that you might be returning at the `return` just after `errorLabel.isHidden = false`, because one of the text label text strings in the `if let` above is empty or not a number and thus the `Float` or `Int` initialiser you're passing it into is always failing, causing you to hit the return in the else beneath, and leave the method before you hit the last `if` - Are you absolutely sure that `if` is being called?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, I'm absolutely sure that the last if is called. I put print functions in it and they were called. Only the last else is never been called.

Comment: Got the error.. the index out of bounds was because I had the line

Comment: let setToSave = excercisesFromPlan![excerciseCounter].sets[setCounter]       This must be    let setToSave = excercisesFromPlan![excerciseCounter].sets[setCounter - 1]